# Hover with background image stops loading indication in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, hover, http-post

In my asp.net webform page I have a simple form with a single inputfield and a submit button. When initiating the post request and then hover over the submit button, the browser stops showing the loading state (progress bar dissapears, the "Done" label appears and the loading animation in the tab becomes the site icon again.

I have been able to narrow the bug down to the followihg css rule:

```
.button:hover {  
    background-image:url("/content/images/buttonHoverGradient.jpg");  
}
```

on the following html

```
<input type="submit" class="button" title="Select a provider" value="Select">
```

It seems to me IE initiates the request to fetch the image and then takes the status of this new request as the overal status. I don't have a clue how to prove this. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**
The buttons class is used all over the page and we cannot know the dimensions of them on beforehand. Therefore using a single background as suggested by [@teresko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858910/hover-with-background-image-stops-loading-indication-in-ie7/5859054#5859054) image with several states embedded is not an option.

**UPDATE**
It seems to be in other versions of IE too. Some research seems to point to the Doctype (which is currently quircks as asp.net webforms 3.5 doesn't really alow for strict)

Comment: +1 I don't know but I'm curious to know the answer as well!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to just use a same image for both normal and :hover state of the button , and only change the position of image on mouseover? Kinda like in [this example](http://wellstyled.com/css-nopreload-rollovers.html).

This should solve at least part of the problem.

Comment: This is sound advice, but we don't know how long our buttons will be (translation, varying labels all over the site etc).

Comment: if you have unknown length of element, then just use two pieces : [Sliding doors](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/slidingdoors/) methods .. just make it work with the solution above. Just remember that semi-transparency, image-positions and IE7 doesn't play well together - just fake the transparency.

Comment: oh my. Sliding doors for a hover background image on a button? You are right in that this would be a solution, but it's going too far for what we get in return. IE users will just have to live with a quirky browser. Thanks for the suggestions :)